# How to use substitute variable in batch for loop in TeamCity build step?

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, teamcity

I have as string stored in a local batch variable and I am trying to perform the same action as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/918167/how-to-extract-second-word-of-the-string-via-windows-batch) (Extract nth word). I am able to successfully perform the extraction in a `.bat` on a local machine. However, when I implement this in a [TeamCity CommandLine](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/command-line.html) build step:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%A in (%%myvar%%) do set word3=%%A
```

the script throws an error stating:

```
myvarA was unexpected at this time.
```

I have tried removing the `%%` but unfortunately TeamCity then treats the values as build parameters. Am I missing some escape character for TeamCity? How do I properly iterate through the `myvar` variable?

Comment: Environmental variables are referenced with one set of percent symbols. `%myvar%`.

Comment: Post an [mcve].  Are you sure you're invoking `cmd.exe` and not some other interpreter?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for environment variable in teamcity. **i.e :**

> `echo "%%path%%"`